# Command sometimes does not work with LWUIT 1.5

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I use LWUIT 1.5 and in the "`Libraries & Resources`" project property I selected both `LWUIT_MIDP.jar` and `MIDP_IO.jar`.

The problem is that sometimes , usually in the second Form after the main Form and the fourth Form, when I click a Command ( either the left or the right ) then the menu is not shown , in fact it is not a menu but a Dialog. Although when I replace the project property to use the `LWUIT.jar` file of LWUIT 1.4 then I can click the Commands and show the Dialog.

So what should I do to make the Commands work with LWUIT 1.5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be a [bug on LWUIT 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452243/lwuit-command-buttons-not-always-visible). You can try to test current version of LWUIT(Repository version). Checkout from [LWUIT repository.](http://java.net/projects/lwuit/sources/svn/show)  Still it happens means post into LWUIT bug tracker.